# ScrollView presenting a TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to build a page that contains a scrollView which will then present a TableView, but the tableView is not appearing. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
#import "PlayerDetailViewController.h"
#import "RosterTableTableViewController.h"
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface PlayerDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlayerDetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    TableViewController *rtv = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view = rtv.view;
    self.bioScrollView.contentSize = view.frame.size;
    self.bioScrollView.center = view.center;
    self.bioScrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.bioScrollView addSubview:view];

}

@end
```

The PlayerDetailViewController conforms to the ScrollViewDelegate protocol.

Here is an image of what is actually shown (the scroll view in question is under Commitments and Awards):
[image: See here]

The scrollView displays the table just loading... perpetually. What should actually be shown in the scrollView is this:
[image: See here]

Comment: A table view *is* a scroll view. Why do you want to nest it inside another scroll view?

Comment: I don't actually need to next the tableView. I just want to nest SOMEthing so that when I actually build the page I want to nest, I can nest it easily. Is it not possible to nest a tableView inside a scrollView on a page? Or if I wanted to nest a tableView, would I add just a UIView on IB instead of a UIScrollView to my ViewController?

Comment: In theory you can nest just about anything inside of anything, but it's hard to guess where you're going with this. It might help to provide more information about what you're trying to do. Meantime, have you checked to see if `bioScrollView` is `nil`?

Comment: I've updated my post to display an image of what is being shown

Comment: I'm not seeing an image.

Comment: First you said "the tableView is not appearing," but now you're saying, "The scrollView displays the table just loading... perpetually." Those are contradictory statements. The best way to get help on Stack Overflow is to take the time to provide a clear and *accurate* problem statement. Was your table view ever working in the first place?

Comment: I made a mistake. I'm sorry. It looks like it's appearing, partly. The cells do not load, and it's just a blank table. The data is being loaded from the web, however, and methods like "viewdidappear" are being called.

Comment: Since this is a very different problem from the one you originally posted,  it would be best to post a new question and delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```css
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
  }
```

try

```css
- (void)viewWillAppear {
   [super viewWillAppear];
}
```

also do not delete the viewDidLoad part just write the viewWillAppear part under it. If that does not work you can also try

```css
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

And if that doesn't work, leave everything in the viewDidLoad part except for

```
 [self.bioScrollView addSubview:view];
```

put that under the previous code snippet.